Page Metadata not get from metadata.ini file
today i noticed that title of pages are not updated with data stored into metadata.ini file.
For example this is the code from states.php:
    <?php

// Include the database connection file
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] === 'localhost') {
    // Local environment
   
} else {
    // Production environment
    $documentRoot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $hostRoot = "";
}



// Include the database connection file
include_once $documentRoot . '/includes/db.php';


$ini_state_logo = parse_ini_file("statedata/logos.ini"); // Loads the logos for all the pages
// Check if the state has a logo to make sure the user doesn't see a blank page.



if (isset($_GET["state"])) {
    $state = strtoupper($_GET["state"]);
    if (!array_key_exists($state, $ini_state_logo)) {
        header("Location: https://www.countyfairgrounds.net/");
        exit();
    }
} else {
    header("Location: https://www.countyfairgrounds.net/");
    die("Invalid state");
}



$state = htmlspecialchars($_GET["state"]);
$canonicalUrl = "https://countyfairgrounds.net/state.php?state=$state";
echo "<link rel=\"canonical\" href=\"$canonicalUrl\" />";

// Get ad for this state
$sql = "SELECT * FROM adverts WHERE state='$state' AND start_date < NOW() AND end_date > NOW()";


$js = "";
include "statedata/col_data.php"; // Importing bottom widget data - $col_data
include "statedata/ad_data.php"; // importing Ad data - $ad_data
include "widgets/MenuWidget40.php"; // import menu - $MenuWidget

$ini_state_weather = parse_ini_file("statedata/weather.ini");
$ini_state_weather_widget = parse_ini_file("statedata/weatherwidget.ini");
$ini_state_youtube = parse_ini_file("statedata/youtube.ini");
$ini_state_metatag = parse_ini_file("statedata/metatags.ini");
$ini_state_spreaker = parse_ini_file("statedata/spreaker.ini");
$state = strtoupper($state);
$weather = $ini_state_weather[$state];
//@todo; this is a better location than just the state

$weather_widget = '<a class="weatherwidget-io " href="' . $ini_state_weather_widget[$state . "_URL"] . '" data-label_1="' . $ini_state_weather_widget[$state . "_LABEL"] . '" data-label_2="WEATHER" data-theme="pure">' . $ini_state_weather_widget[$state . "_LABEL"] . '</a>';



// Code to make sure logo is updated automatically every month
$dtoToday = new DateTime();
$currMonth = $dtoToday->format("F");
$currYear = $dtoToday->format("Y");
$urlLogo = str_replace("MONTH", $currMonth, $ini_state_logo[$state]);


// custom advert 

// Get the current date
$currentDate = date("Y-m-d");

// Perform the query to retrieve the adverts for the specified state and current date
$query = "SELECT * FROM adverts WHERE state = '$state' AND start_date <= '$currentDate' AND end_date >= DATE_ADD('$currentDate', INTERVAL 1 DAY)";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$custom_advert = "";

if ($result) {
    // Check if there are any adverts
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // Fetch the single record
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        $banner_link = $row['banner_link'];
        $banner_text = $row['banner_text'];
        $banner_text_color = $row['banner_text_color'];
        $banner_text_size = $row['banner_text_size'];
        $href = !empty($banner_link) ? $banner_link : "#";
        $custom_advert = '';
    
        
        if ($row['embeded_video']) {
            $custom_advert = '
            <div class="video-container mt-4">
                <iframe width="420" height="315"  src="' . $row['embeded_video'] . '" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="2"
            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
            referrerpolicy="strict-origin-when-cross-origin" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                <a href="' . $href . '" target="_blank">
                    <p style="color: ' . $banner_text_color . '; font-size: ' . $banner_text_size . 'px;">' . $banner_text . '</p>
                </a>
            </div>';
        } else if ($row['embeded_vimeo_video']) {
            $custom_advert = '
            <div class="video-container mt-4">
                <iframe class="embeded_vimeo_video" src="' . $row['embeded_vimeo_video'] . '"  width="420" height="315" frameborder="2" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                <a href="' . $href . '" target="_blank">
                    <p style="color: ' . $banner_text_color . '; font-size: ' . $banner_text_size . 'px;">' . $banner_text . '</p>
                </a>
            </div>';
        } else if ($row['banner_image']) {
            $imagePath = 'https://countyfairgrounds.net/uploads/' . $row['banner_image'];
            $custom_advert = '<a href="' . $href . '" target="_blank">
                                  <img src="' . $imagePath . '" alt="Banner Image" class="img-fluid custom-advert rounded">
                                  <p style="color: ' . $banner_text_color . '; font-size: ' . $banner_text_size . 'px;">' . $banner_text . '</p>
                               </a>';
        } else {
            // a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#contactModal"
            $imagePath = $hostRoot . '/images/advert/rent-ad-space.png';
            $custom_advert = '<div class=""> ' . gettype($row['banner_video'])  . ' <a href="https://countyfairgrounds.net/sitestuff/sitestuff.php" > <img src="' . $imagePath . '" alt="Rent ad space available" class="img-fluid w-75 rounded " ></a>  </div>';
        }
    } else {
        // a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#contactModal"
        $imagePath = $hostRoot . '/images/advert/rent-ad-space.png';
        $custom_advert = '<div class=""> <a href="https://countyfairgrounds.net/sitestuff/sitestuff.php" > <img src="' . $imagePath . '" alt="Rent ad space available" class="img-fluid w-75 rounded " ></a>  </div>';
    }
} else {
    // Handle the error
    echo "Error executing query: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}


// sidebar advert 
$query_sidebar = "SELECT * FROM sidebar_adverts WHERE state = '$state' AND start_date <= '$currentDate' AND end_date >= DATE_ADD('$currentDate', INTERVAL 1 DAY)";
$sidebar_result = mysqli_query($conn, $query_sidebar);

$custom_sidebar_advert = "";

if ($sidebar_result) {
    
   
    // Check if there are any adverts
    if (mysqli_num_rows($sidebar_result) > 0) {
        // Fetch the single record

        
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sidebar_result);


        $banner_link = $row['banner_link'];
        $banner_text = $row['banner_text'];
        $banner_text_color = $row['banner_text_color'];
        $banner_text_size = $row['banner_text_size'];
        $href = !empty($banner_link) ? $banner_link : "#";
        $custom_sidebar_advert = '';
        

            


        if ($row['banner_video']) {
            $banner_video_path = $hostRoot . '/uploads/videos/' . $row['banner_video'];
            $custom_sidebar_advert .= '
            <div class="video-container mt-4">
                <video width="420" height="315" controls style="width:100%;">
                    <source src="' . $banner_video_path . '" type="video/mp4">
                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                </video>
                <a href="' . $href . '" target="_blank">
                    <p style="color: ' . $debug_output . '; font-size: ' . $banner_text_size . 'px;">' . $banner_text . '</p>
                </a>
            </div>';
        } else if ($row['embeded_video']) {

            $custom_sidebar_advert = '
            <div class="video-container mt-4">
                <iframe width="420" height="315" src="' . $row['embeded_video'] . '" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="2"
            allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
            referrerpolicy="strict-origin-when-cross-origin" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                <a href="' . $href . '" target="_blank">
                <p style="color: ' . $banner_text_color . '; font-size: ' . $banner_text_size . 'px " >' . $banner_text . '</p>
                    
                </a>
            </div>';
        }
        else if ($row['embeded_vimeo_video'])
        {

            $custom_sidebar_advert = '
            <div class="video-container mt-4">
                <iframe class="embeded_vimeo_video" src="' . $row['embeded_vimeo_video'] . '"  width="420" height="315" frameborder="2" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

                <a href="' . $href . '" target="_blank">
                <p style="color: ' . $banner_text_color . '; font-size: ' . $banner_text_size . 'px " >' . $banner_text . '</p>
                    
                </a>
            </div>';
        } 
        else if($row['banner_image']){
            $imagePath = 'https://countyfairgrounds.net/uploads/' . $row['banner_image'];

            $custom_sidebar_advert = '<a href="' . $href . '" target="_blank">
                                  <img src="' . $imagePath . '" alt="Banner Image" class="img-fluid custom-sidebar-advert rounded">
                                  <p style="color: ' . $banner_text_color . '; font-size: ' . $banner_text_size . 'px;">' . $banner_text . '</p>
                               </a>';
        } else {
            // a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#contactModal"
            $imagePath = $hostRoot . '/images/advert/rent-ad-space.png';
            $custom_sidebar_advert =  ' <div class=""> <a href="https://countyfairgrounds.net/sitestuff/sitestuff.php" > <img src="' . $imagePath . '" alt="Rent ad space available" class="img-fluid w-100 rounded " >  </a>  </div>';
        }
    } else {
        // a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#contactModal"
        $imagePath = $hostRoot . '/images/advert/rent-ad-space.png';
        $custom_sidebar_advert =  ' <div class=""> <a href="https://countyfairgrounds.net/sitestuff/sitestuff.php" > <img src="' . $imagePath . '" alt="Rent ad space available" class="img-fluid w-100 rounded " ></a>  </div>';
    }
} else {
    // Handle the error
    echo "Error executing query: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}


// Code to generate metatags and title stuff
$Metag = $ini_state_metatag[$state . "_meta_stuff"];
$titstuff = $ini_state_metatag[$state . "_title_stuff"];

// Code to generate Youtube videos
$urlYouTube = $ini_state_youtube[$state];
$titleYouTube = $ini_state_youtube[$state . "_Title"];
$textYouTube = $ini_state_youtube[$state . "_Text"];

$youtubeCode = "";

if ($titleYouTube != "") {
    $youtubeCode =
        '
            <div class="card mb-4">
                <div class="card-heading p-2 text-white">
                    ' .
        $titleYouTube .
        '
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p>
                    ' .
        $textYouTube .
        '
                    </p>
                    <br />
                    <div class="embed-container embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        ' .
        $urlYouTube .
        '
                    </div>
                </div>
                  </div>';
}

// Code to generate spreaker podcasts
$urlSpreaker = $ini_state_spreaker[$state . "_url"];
$episode_id = $ini_state_spreaker[$state . "_episode_id"];
$titleSpreaker = $ini_state_spreaker[$state . "_title"];

$spreakerCode = "";

if ($titleSpreaker != "") {
    $spreakerCode =
        '<h3 style="background-color:#400000 ;color: #FFFFFF; padding: 2%" class="lead">Check Out the latest local Podcast! from CoolKay!</h3> <div id="spreaker" style=""> <a class="spreaker-player"   href="' .
        $urlSpreaker .
        '" data-resource="episode_id=' .
        $episode_id .
        '"
                         data-width="100%" data-height="200px" data-theme="light" data-playlist="false" data-playlist-continuous="false" data-autoplay="false" 
                         data-live-autoplay="false" data-chapters-image="true" data-episode-image-position="right" data-hide-logo="false" data-hide-likes="false" data-hide-comments="false" 
                         data-hide-sharing="false" data-hide-download="true">Listen to "' .
        $titleSpreaker .
        '" on Spreaker.</a>  </div>';
}

// code to generate bottom widgets

$columncount = count($col_data[$state]);

$cols = round(12 / $columncount);


?>


<?php
$currentYear = date('Y');
$pageDescription = $Metag;
$pageTitle = $titstuff;
$twitterImage = "https://www.countyfairgrounds.net/images/Airplane/CountyFairs.png";
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/header.php';
?>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="weather/css/weatherslider.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/state.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/jquery-ui.css" />
<!-- weather css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="weather/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-image: none !important;
        background: #e1c699 !important;
    }

    .custom-advert {
        width: 360px !important;
        height: 320px;
    }
    
    .custom-sidebar-advert {
        width: 336px !important;
        min-height: 280px;
    }

    .weatherwidget-io {
        width: 320px
    }

    #weather {
        max-width: 100%;
        /* overflow: hidden; */
        height: 340px !important;
    }

    @import url(//www.google.com/cse/api/branding.css);
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
        .banner-img {
            width: 100vw !important;
        }

        .airplane-banner {
            width: 100vw !important;
        }
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
        .banner-img {
            width: 50vw !important;
        }

        .airplane-banner {
            width: 30vw !important;
            margin-top: 2%;
        }

        iframe {
            width: 100% !important
        }

        ;
    }
    
    .state-icon {
        width: 3rem !important;
        height: 3rem !important;
    }

    img {
        width: 10vw !important;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        img {
            width: 35vw !important;
        }
        
        .embeded_vimeo_video {
            height: auto;
        }
    }

    .card-heading {
        background: #400905;
    }

    label {
        color: #000000 !important;
    }

    iframe {
        width: 100%
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 630px) {

        /* show on small screen */
        #sweatherMap {
            display: block;
            height: 50px !important;
            width: 100px !important;
            position: fixed;
            top: 10px;
            right: 3px;
            z-index: 10000;
            margin: 0;
        }

        #sweatherMap #sweatherTemp {
            font-size: 16px !important;
        }

        #sweatherMap #sweatherCityName {
            font-size: 13px !important;
        }

        #sweatherMap #sflex-cont {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-around;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100%;
            color: #fff;
        }

        #sweatherMap #child2>div {
            margin: -10px
        }

        #sweatherMap #schild2 img {
            width: 30px !important;
        }
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 631px) {
        #sweatherMap {
            display: block;
            height: 60px !important;
            width: 150px;
            position: fixed;
            top: 5px;
            right: 150px;
            z-index: 1000;
            margin: 0;
        }

        #sweatherMap #sweatherTemp {
            font-size: 20px !important;
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        #sweatherMap #sweatherCityName {
            font-size: 16px !important;
            margin-top: 1px;
        }

        #sweatherMap #sflex-cont {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-around;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100%;
            color: #fff;
        }

        #sweatherMap #schild2>div {
            margin: -30px
        }

        #sweatherMap #schild2 img {
            width: 100px !important;
        }
    }
</style>




</head>

<body>
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
    <?php echo $MenuWidget; ?>

    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-lg-10 col-sm-10 text-center topbanner">
            <!-- Work on here -->
            <?php
            if (isset($_GET["state"]) && !empty($_GET["state"])) {
                $usStates = file_get_contents(
                    __DIR__ . "/files/us-states.json"
                );
                $usStates = json_decode($usStates);

                $state = strtoupper($_GET["state"]);
                $state_name = "";

                foreach ($usStates as $key => $info) {
                    if ($info->{'state'} == $state) {
                        $state_name = $info->{'name'};
                        $state_name = strtoupper($state_name);
                    }
                }
                $month = date("F");
                $month = ucfirst($month);
            }
            if (!empty($state_name)) { ?>
                <img src="https://countyfairgrounds.net/images/<?php echo $month; ?>/<?php echo str_replace(
                       " ",
                       "",
                       $state_name
                   ); ?>.png" class="img-fluid airplane-banner" alt="Countyfairgrounds USA" />
            <?php }
            ?>
            <br />
            <img src="https://countyfairgrounds.net/images/<?php echo $month; ?>/Countyfairgrounds.png"
                class="img-fluid banner-img" alt="Countyfairgrounds USA" />

        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /container navbar -->
    <div class="container-fluid px-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 ">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 mt-4">
                        <?php echo $spreakerCode; ?>

                        <br />

                        <?php
                            echo $custom_sidebar_advert;
                           
                            // Get the current date
                            $current_date = new DateTime();
                            
                            // Set the target date (December 25th)
                            $target_date = new DateTime('2024-12-25');
                    

                            if ($state == 'NE'  && $current_date <= $target_date) {
                                echo '
                                <h4 class="mb-2">Listen to SANTA here</h4>
                                <audio controls>
                                    <source src="/mp3/santa-w-todd-brauch.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                                    Your browser does not support the audio element.
                                </audio>';
                            }
                        ?>
                        
                        <br /> 

                        
                    <!-- /Col 1 -->
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 mt-4">
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5">

                                <?php echo $youtubeCode; ?>

                            </div>
                            <!-- / Top Col 2 -->

                            <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7">
                                <?php
                                    echo $custom_advert;
                                ?>

                            </div>
                            <!-- / Top Col 3-->
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mt-4">
                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">

                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-heading text-white p-2">
                                        Event List
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body text-center text-dark" id="EventsList">
                                        <table id="htmlEventTable" class="responsive" width="100%">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Events</th>
                                                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>

                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /col 2 -->
                </div>
                <!-- /row -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Container -->
    
    <div class="modal fade" id="contactModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="contactModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="contactModalLabel">Advert</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="contactForm">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <h4> </h4>
                    
                </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="email" class="form-label">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required>
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="state" name="state" value="<?php echo $state; ?>">
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="message" class="form-label">Write details about your adverts</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" rows="3" required></textarea>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Footer -->

    <script defer src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
         
    <script defer src="/js/plugins.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="js/state_events.js"></script>-->
    <script src="js/state.js"></script>
    <script defer>
        <?php echo $js; ?>
        
        function showAlert(message, alertType) {
    var alertElement = document.createElement('div');
    alertElement.classList.add('alert', 'alert-' + alertType);
    alertElement.setAttribute('role', 'alert');
    alertElement.textContent = message;

    var container = document.getElementById('contactForm');
    container.appendChild(alertElement);

    // Automatically close the alert after 5 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
        alertElement.remove();
         location.reload();
    }, 5000);
}
        
        document.getElementById('contactForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        var form = event.target;
        var formData = new FormData(form);
    
        fetch('send_advert_email.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        }).then(function(response) {
            if (response.ok) {
        
                alert('Thank you... CoolKay will get back to you soon!', 'success');
                form.reset();
                var modal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(document.getElementById('contactModal'));
                modal.hide();
            } else {

                showAlert('Internal server error!', 'error');
            }
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
    });
    
    

// Usage example



    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" defer>
        function init() {
            var vidDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
            for (var i = 0; i < vidDefer.length; i++) {
                if (vidDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
                    vidDefer[i].setAttribute('src', vidDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
                }
            }
        }
        window.onload = init;
    </script>

    <script>
        ! function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = 'https://weatherwidget.io/js/widget.min.js';
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }
        }(document, 'script', 'weatherwidget-io-js');
    </script>
</body>

</html>

and this is one example from metatags.ini file, for example
https://website.com/state.php?state=AZ
//AZ = Alabama
AZ_meta_stuff = "somedata for title"
AZ_title_stuff = "somedata"

Someone to help me why is not getting the data? I have included the entire states.php page code for refference.

Your code is incomplete. You don't show how you're setting $state, or how you use $pageDescription and $titstuff to set the page title. There's nothing here related to MySQL.

I updated the question with code included. Pls check once again.

Why do you use htmlspecialchars($_GET['state'])? Do you really encode the state codes using HTML entities? Why would you need that when they're always just two letter?

Your script is vulnerable to SQL Injection Attack. Even if you are escaping variables, its not safe! You should always use prepared statements and parameterized queries in either MYSQLI or PDO instead of concatenating variables into the query.

Not sure why is that coded like that. That was made from developer who made that site.

Anyway, there's nothing that uses $pageTitle or $pageDescription. Maybe you need something like <title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></title>

None of the MySQL stuff seems to have anything to do with setting the page title, I'm not sure why you included that.

Please post just a [mre]. We don't need all the code, just what's actually relevant to your question, which is about using the ini file, not the DB.

Noted that this part of code is vital for that thing..
"$currentYear = "date('Y')";"
so when manipulate this string, makes the changes

Why? That variable is never used.

I dont know, but when replace for ex. $currentYear = "date('Y')"; and replace "date('Y') with something like "test" it print test into tab..

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
